# Binding from ItemsSource context

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datacontext

I'm having a problem with the DataContext and the Title. The following works as intended:

```
 <chartingToolkit:LineSeries Title={Binding TrendDaily.Name} ItemsSource="{Binding TrendDaily.Progress}">
 //...
 </chartingToolkit:LineSeries>
```

But the Title should contain more information so I'm doing this:

```
<chartingToolkit:LineSeries ItemsSource="{Binding TrendDaily.Progress}">
  <chartingToolkit:LineSeries.Title>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding TrendDaily.Name}"/>
      <TextBlock Text="-test text"/>
    </StackPanel>
  </chartingToolkit:LineSeries.Title>
  //...
</chartingToolkit:LineSeries>
```

I figured out the Title binding doesn't work because it has the "Progress" elements as his context but I wasn't able to find a working binding.

Edit:
The complete new code with binding error (Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=LineName'):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns:chartingToolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<chartingToolkit:Chart Title="Trend">
    <chartingToolkit:Chart.Series>            
        <chartingToolkit:LineSeries DataContext="{Binding TrendDaily}"
ItemsSource="{Binding Progress}" DependentValuePath="Value" IndependentValuePath="Key" x:Name="LineName">
            <chartingToolkit:LineSeries.Title>
                <TextBlock>
                            <Run Text="{Binding DataContext.Name, ElementName=LineName}"/>
                            <Run Text="*"/>                                
                </TextBlock>
            </chartingToolkit:LineSeries.Title>                
        </chartingToolkit:LineSeries>
    </chartingToolkit:Chart.Series>
</chartingToolkit:Chart>
</Window>
```

Code Behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public TrendDailyClass TrendDaily { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        TrendDaily = new TrendDailyClass();
        DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

public class TrendDailyClass
{
    public Dictionary<string, double> Progress { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public TrendDailyClass()
    {
        Progress = new Dictionary<string, double>();
        Progress.Add("10", 10);
        Progress.Add("20", 20);
        Name = "test";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bind `TrendDaily` to the `DataContext` of `LineSeries`, then use `DataContext` in the inner bindings, using `ElementName` as:

```
<chartingToolkit:Chart Title="Trend"
                     DataContext="{Binding TrendDaily}"
                     x:Name="LineName">
   <chartingToolkit:LineSeries ItemsSource="{Binding Progress}">
     <chartingToolkit:LineSeries.Title>
       <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.Name, ElementName=LineName}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="-test text"/>
       </StackPanel>
     </chartingToolkit:LineSeries.Title>
     //...
  </chartingToolkit:LineSeries>
```

Moreover, there is no need to use two `TextBlock`.. You can use `Run` (which is very lightweight class) as:

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
       <TextBlock>
          <Run Text="{Binding DataContext.Name, ElementName=LineName}"/>
          <Run Text="-test text"/>
       </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
```

It's better, as it avoids unnecessary visual element. Classes derived from `UIElement` are relatively heavier.

Comment: It seems this doesn't work for me. I get the following error:
BindingExpression path error: 'Name' property not found on 'object' ''LineDataPoint' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=Name; DataItem='LineDataPoint' (Name=''); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')

Comment: @michael: Sorry, I had forgotten to use `ElementName`. Anyway, I edied my answer. Note that I used `x:Name` on `LineSeries`.

Comment: Now I get:
Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=LineName'. BindingExpression:Path=Name; DataItem=null; target element is 'Run' (HashCode=54686603); target property is 'Text' (type 'String') - from my understanding this should work as I have added the x:Name and the Element name.

Comment: @michael: You're using `{Binding Name, ElementName=LineName}`.. not `{Binding DataContext.Name, ElementName=LineName}`, right? Use the latter.

Comment: Yes, I was using the first one but with the second one I get the same error:Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=LineName'. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.Name; DataItem=null; target element is 'Run' (HashCode=47843779); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')

Comment: Yes, i have edited my initial post the part after "Edit:" is the complete code I use to get the binding error.

Comment: @michael: Alright, You're using `Run`. Maybe, that is causing some problem which I'm unaware of. Is your code working if you use TextBlock, instead?

Comment: TextBlock and Label produce the same error - Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=LineName'.

Comment: @michael: I guess, `x:Name` cannot be applied to `LineSeries`, as maybe it doesn't have `Name` property. Anyway, in my edited answer, I moved `x:Name` and `DataContext` binding to `Chart` element. As `Chart` is a visual, it should work now.

Comment: I tried the moving up but its the same. Even RelativeSource didn't work for me. To me it looks like a problem with the chartingToolkit. I will probably have to create the title text in code behind.

Answer (score 0):

If you're first code example is working, you should be able to use the [`StringFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat.aspx) property in your first binding:

```
<chartingToolkit:LineSeries Title={Binding TrendDaily.Name, StringFormat='{}{0}-test text'} ItemsSource="{Binding TrendDaily.Progress}">
//...
</chartingToolkit:LineSeries>
```